# Construct DatetimeIndex if you only have year

Tags: python, pandas

I have data of the structure

```
     country  year        POP
606  Algeria  1966  12339.140
730  Algeria  1968  13146.267
793  Algeria  1969  13528.304
856  Algeria  1970  13931.846
924  Algeria  1971  14335.388
```

Now I want to create first-differences per country based on the year (difference per year). If it weren't for the interval concern, I'd do something along the lines of

```
df.sort(['country', 'year']).set_index(['country', 'year']).diff()
```

Instead, I guess I have to convert `year` `to_datetime()` first. Is there a simple way to create the datetime from a column that contains years only? And is there a different more natural approach to create the differences over time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do

```
df.set_index(df.year.map(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x, 1, 1)))
```

That uses the concept of left-open intervals.

Another possibility is

```
df.set_index(df.year.map(pd.Period))
```

Both return equally well-defined indexes, in the latter case you might like the output of `df.diff()` better since it actually states a year.

Comment: FYI, you can create the index by ``pd.PeriodIndex(df.year,freq='Y')`` as well

Comment: Nice. One related follow-up: `.diff()` is not computed relative to the index: if the index jumps by (say) two years, the computed result is not divided by two. Is there no built-in functionality for this?

Comment: `diff` is just the difference, if you want the difference quotient instead you can do `df.POP.diff() / pd.Series(df.index, index=df.index).diff()`. `diff` on an index means set-difference, so you have to convert it to a series first.